# Jquery not reacting to anything

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery snippet. Since it is not passing me the value, I am going into all sort of ways to figure out why, including function call backs to see what is going on. Yet nothing gets displayed. Two different examples

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//jquery code for source list
$(document).ready(function()
     {
      $('#country').change(function() 
         {
            if ($(this).val()!='') 
              {
                $("#source").load("/CI-3/application/controllers/control_form.php",   {pais_id: $(this).val()}, function() 
            {
          alert('Load was not performed.'));
            }

    });

});  // end of country and city function
</script>
```

So this is the selectlist that should activate the jquery upon changing value:

```
<?php echo form_open('control_form/add_all'); ?>
       <label for="country">Country<span class="red"></span></label>
        <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php

                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                echo '<option value="' . $row->pais_id . '">' . $row->pais_name . '</option>';
                }

            ?>
        </select>
```

And a different example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
        {
             $('#country').change(function() 
                  {
                  if ($(this).val()!='') 
                      {
                               $("#loquesea").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) 
                                    {
                                if (status == "error") 
                                      {
                                          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                                          $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                                          }
                                });


                         });
                  });

                 });



</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<div id="success"></div>
<b>Error Response:</b>
<div id="error"></div>


<form action="">
<select id = "country" name="country">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your Network tab on Chrome dev tools or Net tab in Firebug to see if the request actually gets sent.. and what it returns.

Comment: Nothing happens and shows when I use the select list, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not element in your html with id source so your selector will `$("#source")`

Change

```
$("#source")
```

to

```
$("#success")
```

There is `}` bracket was missing for `if ($(this).val() != ''){`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#country').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $("#loquesea").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }

        });
    });
```

Comment: That was not what the OP asked for. Besides, we don't know if there is such an element in the rest of the HTML (the rest that the OP didn't post); anyway the problem is that the value is not returned, most likely because of a syntax error.

Comment: Yes this is also one of the problem I added one more

Comment: Yes, I've already removed my downvote, didn't see the second HTML, sorry mate.

Answer (score 1):

There are *lots* errors with parentheses. Fix them and your code will work. Use correct indentation as a guide.

```
$(document).ready(
     function()
     {
         $('#country').change(
             function() 
             {
                 if ($(this).val()!='') 
                 {
                        $("#source").load("/CI-3/application/controllers/control_form.php",   
                                          {pais_id: $(this).val()}, 
                                           function() 
                                                  {
                                             alert('Load was not performed.'); // 1st fix
                                                }
                                         ); // 2nd fix

                  } 
                } // 3rd fix... and so on
```